# Can I destroy a shader module if a pipeline uses it as one of the stages?

Tags: vulkan

Let's say I make a pipeline specifying a module for vertex shader and a module for fragment shader. That pipeline is now created. Do I need to keep the original modules around or are they no longer needed as the pipeline has incorporated their code into its own code?

Answer (score 4):

To quote the [spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.3/html/chap9.html#vkDestroyShaderModule) <sub>[archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20220126051300/https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.3/html/chap9.html#vkDestroyShaderModule)</sub> for `vkDestroyShaderModule`

> A shader module **can** be destroyed while pipelines created using its shaders are still in use.